# Javascript Passing parameters to root $(function () {..}) into .js

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, parameters

i have a .js file and i want to pass the parameters to use in the file root of the file

```
$(function () {

    var defaults = {
      usernameFlag: false,
      passwordFlag: false
     };

    var options;

    var getFlags = {
        parameters: function(args) {
            options = $.extend({}, defaults, args);     
            console.log(options);       
            }
    };
    console.log(options);
});
```

this is my body content

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  getFlags.parameters({ usernameFlag: true, passwordFlag: false});
</script>
```

In practice, I want to pass values ​​from the body to a js file and initialize options with the sent values

Comment: getFlags is not defined in the window scope. you cant access a private variable like that. also anonymous function not executed.

Answer (score 0):

Just export the function to the global object:

`window.getFlags = ...`

Answer (score -1):

You should be able to accomplish this simply by adding a `src='/path/to/your/script.js'` into your opening script tag.